# Using templated struct as argument in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, templates, opencl

I am running into a problem for which I would be incredibly grateful if you could help me a solution.

I am trying to compile the code snippet seen below using `clang-17`, but get the error:

`openclTemplateTest.hpp:12:68: error: '__global MyTemplatedTestStructWithSize *__private' (aka '__global MyTemplatedTestStruct<32> *__private') cannot be used as the type of a kernel parameter`

The complete list of `clang` arguments is as follows:

`/usr/lib/llvm-17/bin/clang++ -c -cl-std=clc++ -target spir64 -emit-llvm -fcolor-diagnostics -Xclang -finclude-default-header -I[some header includes for OpenCL-C++] openclTemplateTest.hpp -o bitcode_out.bc`

The first guess is that OpenCL kernels do not support arrays of templated structs as arguments, but that’s not true, is it? At least I could not find a restriction like that in the documentation. If they are allowed in general, what am I doing wrong? Is it an address space problem? I am confused by the error `clang`-generated error message (why does it throw in `__private` there?)

Thank you very much in advance!

The code in question:

```cpp
template<unsigned int NUM_BLOCKS>
struct MyTemplatedTestStruct
{
    int data[NUM_BLOCKS];
};

typedef MyTemplatedTestStruct<32> MyTemplatedTestStructWithSize;

kernel void myTestFunction(__global MyTemplatedTestStructWithSize* myArgument)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        myArgument->data[i] = 42; // completely nonsensical, just for testing purposes
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why it works, but, under your `typedef`, make a declaration: `__global MyTemplatedTestStructWithSize dummy;` - nothing more. I assume these `__global` declared variables are the only ones you are then allowed to pass into a function taking a pointer to a `__global`.

Comment: It seems to be a Clang bug, see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58590 and linked issues

Comment: @UnholySheep Seems to be correct. You can simply do `template class MyTemplatedTestStruct<32>;` after the class template definition to explicitly instantiate the class template.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly! I had a feeling that it must be possible but wouldn't have thought of navigating around that `clang` bug by instantiating the class template. You guys deserve a Bier/öl for that!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the replies, the problem is a `clang` [bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58590), making kernel parameter diagnostics "too conservative or sometimes even incorrect".

One solution is to tell `clang` to allow the use of restricted types in kernel parameters, as described here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#cl-clang-non-portable-kernel-param-types

Another solution is to instantiate the template class via `template class MyTemplatedTestStruct<32>;` after the class declaration.